# Train Pulse Detection on software

Tags: python, signal-processing

I need to detect a square pulse train on software, and retain the amplitude of the last received pulse until the next one is measured.

The period is between certain values, say 1 and 1.5 seconds, but I don't have a priori knowledge of the exact value, only these limits.

Similarly, the duty cycle is between 5 and 10%, I only know these limits.

The amplitude of the signal may and will fade during its whole duration.

For every period I need to return (and buffer)  the pulse amplitude, or the power of the signal.

---

Right know I'm using some custom digital filtering, windowing the signal and retaining the maximum read in the last 1.5 seconds.
The behaviour is kind of acceptable, but it's a very sensitive to noise and... Let’s say unprofessional approach.

Using Fourier transform doesn't really help as the duty cycle is so small it's unfeasible to extract clean information from there. (I tried already)

Using convolution in an optimal fashion to get the energy isn't that easy as the length of the pulse is unknown.

---

So the question is: Do you have any idea or tip on how to improve/optimise the detection?

Thank you!

PS: In case it's relevant for your answer I'm using python 2.7, running on a Raspberry Pi 3.

Comment: Scipy has a lot of SP functions https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/signal.html, including convolution on 2 or n-dimensonal spaced arrays. I have no idea how to use that to fix your problem tho :D https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/signal.html

Comment: It will be nice if you add some raw data (more is better) that are you working with.

Comment: Could you provide some (mock) data ? All the knowledge you have on the signal would be helpful, maybe some code, because we are kind of kept in the dark here. FYI, in spite of what you say, this seems a good way to go.